# Is there a way to get top apps from Facebook App Center?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to programmatically get a list of top rated apps from a specific app center category:

http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/category/games/?platform=allplatforms

I can't find anything inside Graph API or FQL, nor any RSS feeds. Is there any "civilized" way of doing this besides page scrapping?

Comment: CURL is the answer :).

if you need i can write the code for you...

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?